# Probability distribution question including mean and variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The lengths of the drive rods produced by a small engineering company are normally distributed with a mean of 118 cm and a standard deviation of $0.3\ cm$. Rods that have a length of more than $118.37\ cm$ or less than $117.11\ cm$ are rejected. Find the percentage of rods that are rejected.

This is a probability distribution question which I am stuck on. I don't know how to approach the question. I tried finding the value of $p$ by isolating it from the variance formula but I don't think that is the right approach for this question.

Comment: This is not a binomial distribution problem, this is a normal distribution problem.

Comment: Are you familiar with Z-scores? Can you normalize the bounds $118.37$ and $117.11$ into Z-scores, and the use these in conjunction with the standard normal distribution in some way (think area) to find a probability?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this figure will help:

[image]

In *Mathematica*:

```
1 - Integrate[
           PDF[NormalDistribution[118, 0.3], x], 
           {x, 117.11, 118.37}]
```

(* 0.110231 *)

Comment: @Sara: In R, the proportion of rejected rods [shaded here(+1)] is computed using code `1 - diff(pnorm(c(117.11,118.37), 118, .3))`, which returns 0.1102309. You will get a similar value starting with $1 - P(117.11 < X < 118.37),$ standardizing, and using printed normal tables.